# Data Annotations + MVC3 + Culture Issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, data-annotations, globalization, jquery-globalization

I'm having a problem working with Cultures, MVC3 and Data Annotations. I defined a table `STORES` on a spanish database `(COLLATION is set for LATIN_GENERAL);` some of the fields are defined in SQL as `DECIMAL(18,2) NOT NULL`. On my MVC3 Application I already set culture for "es-ES" on the web.config file. Also, I am using all my views strongly-typed.

If I use DataAnnotations for validations, it would automatically add the `Required field` and `The field must be a number` validations. That would be perfect except for one thing:

`The field must be a number` validation is forcing me to use dot(.) as decimal separator instead of comma(,). So, I don't know how to change it nor how to translate this error message. Then I thought I might force the user to use dot instead of comma with jquery (ugly-solution). So, I did it just to make some tests and the result was that it allowed me to pass the validations and created perfectly the object in database.

But here comes the weird, when I'm editting that same object, it's shown on my same strongly typed form with comma as a decimal separator instead of dot. So what's the problem? That the user can't never submit an edition of the object.

What am I doing wrong?

> 1. Added the proper collation to the database.
> 2. Added the globalization attribute on the web.config file.
> 3. I even tried this [MVC 3 jQuery Validation/globalizing of number/decimal field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5199835/mvc-3-jquery-validation-globalizing-of-number-decimal-field)
>      with no success...

Which is the proper way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Is the problem occuring client-side or server side?  ie, does a postback occur before the validation error?

Comment: Client Side. No postback. The validation error is javascripted. I assume it has to do with how jquery deals with decimal separators.

Comment: Old question but this did the trick for me : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5199835/mvc-3-jquery-validation-globalizing-of-number-decimal-field

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can either turn off client-side validation, or apply some hacks such as this:

http://blog.brainnovative.com/2010/12/globalizing-aspnet-mvc-unobtrusive.html

Comment: I tried the hack of your link, step by step as it is but I get the javascript error: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'es-ES' of undefined"...did it work for you?

Comment: @met.lord - it looks like things have changed a bit, so you'll have to adapt.  Did you download the jquery globalization here? https://github.com/jquery/globalize

Comment: I installed it through NuGet... then downloaded the cultures files from there (github.com/jquery/globalize)

Comment: @met.lord - this article is a bit better, and describes globalization of unobtrusive validation. http://afana.me/post/aspnet-mvc-internationalization-part-2.aspx

Comment: Tried everything, then realized some of the methods changed name. So I managed to keep the logic and tried with the new methods but didn't succeed on having the unobtrusive validation working properly on spanish...