# MVC 4 Culture conflict

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, unobtrusive-javascript

I'm working on a intranet web application using MVC 4 and Entity Framework. Since the beginning of the development, I have an issue which I couldn't resolve. To illustrate what I'm saying, here is an example :

I can add a Person throught a "Create View". In this view, I have to precise a decimal number which represents the distance between the person's house and the work place. At this stage, everything's fine. However, when I want to edit a Person and want to save the changes, the number is not accepted as a decimal number.

I read about my problem and I tried things like add a  tag in the web.config and precise the culture I want to use (to be precise, the french culture).

Here is my "Edit View" :

```
@model BuSIMaterial.Models.Person
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
}
<h2>
    Edit</h2>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jQueryFixes.js")" type = "text/javascript"></script>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Person</legend>
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id_Person)
        <div class="editor-label">
            First name :
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.FirstName, new { maxlength = 50 })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            Last name :
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.LastName, new { maxlength = 50 })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LastName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            National number :
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.NumNat, new { maxlength = 11 })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.NumNat)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            Start date :
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.StartDate, new { @class = "datepicker" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.StartDate)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            End date :
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.EndDate, new { @class = "datepicker" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EndDate)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            Distance House - Work (km) :
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.HouseToWorkKilometers)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.HouseToWorkKilometers)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            Category :
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DropDownList("Id_ProductPackageCategory", "Choose one ...")
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Id_ProductPackageCategory) <a href="../ProductPackageCategory/Create">
                Add a new category?</a>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            Upgrade? :
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Upgrade)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Upgrade)
        </div>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Save" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}
<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

Do you have any idea to solve this problem? It is very annoying and unfortunatelly, I didn't find a way to resolve it.

EDIT : Edit Method (Person controller) :

```
    public ActionResult Edit(long id = 0)
    {
        Person person = db.Persons.Single(p => p.Id_Person == id);
        if (person == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        ViewBag.Id_ProductPackageCategory = new SelectList(db.ProductPackageCategories, "Id_ProductPackageCategory", "Name", person.Id_ProductPackageCategory);
        return View(person);
    }

    //
    // POST: /Person/Edit/5

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(Person person)
    {

        ViewBag.Id_ProductPackageCategory = new SelectList(db.ProductPackageCategories, "Id_ProductPackageCategory", "Name", person.Id_ProductPackageCategory);

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            ModelStateDictionary errorDictionary = Validator.isValid(person);

            if (errorDictionary.Count > 0)
            {
                ModelState.Merge(errorDictionary);
                return View(person);
            }

            db.Persons.Attach(person);
            db.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(person, EntityState.Modified);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(person);
    }
```

Comment: What kind of error do you get? Or is it just cut off at the decimal places or just converted to an int?

Comment: Do the unobtrusive Javascript validation results differ from the server side ones? We had a similar issue with decimal separators but only the server-side validation worked as expected.

Comment: Can you post the code for your Action method as well?

Comment: It seems that it is a client-side error. Indeed, I can't modify my Person without replacing this "," by "." or just by deleting it. And a red error message appears next to my textbox. Here is my action method.

Comment: @Traffy Then your issue might be related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5199835/mvc-3-jquery-validation-globalizing-of-number-decimal-field

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Could you make a post with your solution so I can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the unobtrusive javascript validation results differ from the server side ones, your issue might be related to [MVC 3 jQuery Validation/globalizing of number/decimal field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5199835/mvc-3-jquery-validation-globalizing-of-number-decimal-field).

We had a similar issue and this thread helped to resolve it.