# Price error with model in asp mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I would to be able to edit/add an item without having to edit the price every time. Currently i have to always remove **,00** or change the **,** into a **.** in or for the price input to validate.

If i change the web.config file

```
<globalization enableClientBasedCulture="false" culture="en-US" uiCulture="en-US"/>
```

Then it works. The editable input is displayed with the default value of **.00**. However i am not in America and will not be using dollars.

My model is

```
[Required(ErrorMessage="Please add a price.")]
[DataType(DataType.Currency)]
public decimal Price { get; set; }
```

Comment: I guess you are from Europe because in Europe only "." translates to ","

Comment: I came to editing price as string - it is more easy to validate and convert dot or comma string to desimal

Answer (score 0):

some useful links from where you may find your solution!

[MVC 3 jQuery Validation/globalizing of number/decimal field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5199835/mvc-3-jquery-validation-globalizing-of-number-decimal-field)

http://haacked.com/archive/2010/05/10/globalizing-mvc-validation.aspx/

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg674880(VS.98).aspx