# How to change the delimeter from "," to "." in SQL database for the decimal column

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server

By default, my ASP.NET project creates a table with the decimal column with "," delimeter. All decimals are stored in format "100,10". How can I change the delimeter to "."?

It causes problems with jQuery validation. JQuery thinks that it's not a number and the format of the field is wrong. I don't want to work around with jQuery.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What kind of database are you using (MySql, Sql Server, Oracle, etc) and what is the **exact** data type of the column?

Comment: Database - SQL, datatype- decimal

Comment: There are a number of different kinds of SQL database. Which specific kind of SQL database are you using?

Comment: Okay, the `dbo` in the image indicates MS Sql Server. Oracle, Sqlite, Postgresql, mysql, and access are all also SQL databases, and all of them do this slightly differently under the covers.

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5199835

Answer (score 2):

> All decimals are stored in format "100,10"

This misunderstands what is happening. Sql Server stores decimal values in a binary format that is not human readable.

What you are seeing is more likely formatting applied by your query tool, reporting platform, or chosen by the culture settings in the operating system or process on the client system after data is returned from the database.

Comment: Please, see the images above. So there is no other way to deal with this problem than to fix everything in jquery? When I enter 100.10 in the field, it is stored as 0 in the database.

Comment: Not necessarily in jquery. You also have some C# and aspx markup, and you can sometimes address it at the IIS level, too.

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing *storage* and *representation*.

SQL Server does not store "." or ",", it just stores a binary value.

The representation of decimal numbers in Visual Studio is controlled by your language settings in Windows.

The validation of jquery-validate (? you do not state which mechanism you are using) is controlled by configuration. See [these answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5199835), or the documentation of your library.